# PHP substr loop output

Tags: php, substr, substring

How to loop through  $string text to get all instances at the moment my code only out puts first line  :  fruit apple name stone

How do i make it also check the second line and output :fruit guava name roddy

for example in the $string text below we have :
 foo name stoner and foo name roddy 
 At the moment i can only extract name stoner and script stops.
 I would also like it to extract  name roddy.

sorry if i dont make sense. my english is not that good

```
$string = 'foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas';
$needle = 'fruit';
$needle1 = 'name';
$str = substr($string, strpos($string, $needle) + strlen($needle), 6);
$str1 = substr($string, strpos($string, $needle1) + strlen($needle1), 6);
echo  $needle. $str; 
echo " ";
echo  $needle1. $str1;
```

Comment: What is the desired output? It's hard to understand your requirement.

Comment: Use preg_split, and you can break on any whitespace character, not simply space characters

Comment: Or use str_word_count() to split your string into an array of words

Comment: Is this string being treated as an associative array?

Comment: thanks  I want to loop through the $string  and echo all instances of  
 
echo  $needle. $str;   and  echo  $needle1. $str1; 

  at the moment i can only  echo results from the first  instance. 
for example  i have     

foo name stoner  and than i have foo name koala

At the moment i can extract  name stoner and the script stops.
I would also like to extract    name roddy.

Comment: @user3548161 is foo the line delimiter

Comment: yeah foo is line delimeter

Comment: So it needs to find "foo fruit" then a fruit? EDIT, sorry "foo name" then a name i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this regex, is this what you want?

```
 $string = 'foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas';
preg_match("/(name \w{6}).*(fruit \w{6})/", $string, $output);
```

output:

```
array(3
  0 =>  name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
  1 =>  name stoner
  2 =>  fruit apples
)
array(3
  0 =>  name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas
  1 =>  name roddy
  2 =>  fruit guavas
 )
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fzF

Edited to only match 6 characters, but this means "roddy" line is not matched as it's 5 chars only.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** After the last comments you added to your question, I'm a bit confused and I think I didn't understand your question correctly, so this answer may not be exactly what you want after all...

---

I assume that what you want is to split the string by lines and filter those lines which contain the string. Check this out:

```
<?php

// No HTML output for now, so I added this to make it display properly in the browser
// You can remove this line if you are using `php -f` from the command line instead of a browser
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// Added two more lines for clarification
$string = 'foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas
something here which only contains fruit bla bla test
and this line has name but thats it bla bla bla';

// I guess you will have more needles later, so an array makes sense here
$needles = ['fruit', 'name', 'nothing'];

// Split the string into lines first
$lines = explode("\n", $string);

// Check each needle
foreach($needles as $needle) {
    // Output needle
    echo "Needle: $needle\n";

    // Filter the lines: Check if word is contained
    $matchingLines = array_filter($lines, function($line) use ($needle) {
        // Tells array_filter to include the line if the needle is contained in it
        return strpos($line, $needle) !== false;

        // Note that this currently searches the full line regardless of word
        // boundaries. If you wanted to find full words only (e.g. not `dragonfruit`
        // when searching for `fruit` or something), you could use this:
        //   return in_array($needle, explode(" ", $line));
    });

    // Output results, if any
    if(count($matchingLines)) {
        echo "Results:\n";
        echo implode("\n", $matchingLines);
    } else {
        echo "No results!";
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Needle: fruit
Results:
foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas
something here which only contains fruit bla bla test

Needle: name
Results:
foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples
foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas
and this line has name but thats it bla bla bla

Needle: nothing
No results!
```

Comment: wow great example you have super fast coding skills  it is close but i want to out put   only 6 characters after every  needle  $str = substr($string, strpos($string, $needle) + strlen($needle), 6);

Comment: So always 6 characters, no matter what the word is? Even if it's bananas?

Comment: Well then it is much simpler: You can continue using your code but you just need to put it in a loop and start you search after the position of the last match until you don't find any more match, i.e. use `substr` on your haystack first to cut away the part you already searched in.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys .. lol andreas good point i am just using fruit keyword as example  i am trying to extract 6 characters after a keyword  so for example if i have booking reference as a keyword  than i can extract the booking reference number which is only 6 characters long since it is fixed.

Comment: @user3548161 have you even looked at my answer?

Comment: Wow you guys are great  thanks andreas your answer is good and also nerdlyist  ,if i could upvote both of you i would.  Interesting approach by nerdlyist to just explode the words i wonder which one is more efficient..

Comment: @user3548161 You can always upvote all answers but only accept one.

Comment: @user3548161 in my opinion preg_match beats all loops any day. But it's your project

Comment: @Andreas: No the OP can't because you need 15 reputation to upvote and they have 6. (And I agree with you that `preg_match` is the right tool for this problem probably, provided that the OP's needles and the number of chars are fixed as it now turns out to be.)

Comment: @CherryDT ahh right, the 15 rep limit. Didn't think about that. Yeah, I also think regex will be better, but he seems to keep secrets from us. We have needed to drag everything out of him. If he only gives us real data, not apples and oranges it can be made really good. It's a shame people think the end of the world is comming if they type out real or real but fake data.

Comment: @CherryDT andreas lol no haha ,  I just like coding with Fruits for everything during prototyping.. so when i get frustrated if something dont work i pull an apple out of the fridge and eat it. somehow that calms me down knowing i ate the problematic code. sigh

Comment: Thats because you have made a new capture with (com). Each new () means a new entry in the array. You can add in the echo line `.$output[4][$i]` or you can "open" the capture as I have done here to capture he full email in one entry http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a05e465ef06a602d459ab83a49ba09a5af76f1d do you see the difference in the pattern? You had `(email \w{0,10}.W{0,10}.*w{0,9}).(com)` I have `(email \w{0,10}.W{0,10}.*w{0,9}com)` at the end I removed `).(`

Comment: @user3548161 sorry forgot to tag you. I'm confused about the $pattern, you don't use it. Why is it there? Also you write `$x = preg_match` , but you still have $output in the preg_match. Just to help you. $x and $output is the same in your code. which type you use $x = or $output is up to you, but both is not needed

Comment: @user3548161 so you use my answer in your code but accepted someone elses answer? Great.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks  that was cool..exploring both ways  I am about to change to your answer   since preg_match is more efficient :)

I was planing to use $pattern instead of  (email \w{0,10}.W{0,10}.*w{0,9}com) as it  recognises # % and other nonstandard characters doesn't validate  emails  for now it's cool since   i still have to find out how to do that.

Comment: @user3548161 again, Just a friendly help.  Your code to capture email is a bit... ummm... well I see your edit now :-) If you look at my pattern here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fAp I wrote `email` then `.*` meaning anything, then `\.` means find a dot (backslash escapes . to mean dot) and then `\w+` means find one more complete word.

Comment: @user3548161 Then you can use other real patterns to find out if the email is valid or not. Just google for preg_match email validate and I bet you will find what you need. To make it easier to use the email validate codes you should perhaps use this pattern instead: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fAq notice how I moved the capture of email to not capture "email" but only email... well you see it. This means you have a clean email value

Answer (score 0):

So if based on comments `foo` is a line delimiter and the string is essentially to be treated as an associate array of key => values

```
<?php
    $string = 'foo name stoner loller bar php haystack needle fruit apples foo name roddy koala bar php haystack needle fruit guavas';

    //Get all of the arrays we will need to search
    $hayStacks = explode("foo", $string);

    foreach($hayStacks as $hayStack){
        $words = explode(' ', $hayStack);
        //Enter the key you want to find and then get the next element value.
        echo $words[array_search("name", $words)+1]."<br>";
        echo $words[array_search("fruit", $words)+1]."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the desired result because the OP want to extract a substring with a length of 6 after the keyword match.  This not clearly expressed in the question -- it came later in the comments.